# Dynamically check for strings in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

EDIT: ten months later, I'm still back to this.. still can't figure it out :(

I can search for a string in an array no problem; this works:

```
if (in_array('animals', $value[tags])){
   echo "yes";
}
```

But how can I check for a variable in the array?  This doesn't seem to work:

```
$page_tag = 'animals';
if (in_array($page_tag, $value[tags])){
   echo "yes";
}
```

I'm guessing I'm missing some simple syntax doodad?

The array is massive, so I'll try and show a sample of it.  It is stored on a separate php file and "included" in other places.

```
global $GAMES_REPOSITORY;
$GAMES_REPOSITORY = array   (
     "Kitten Maker"      => array   (
        "num"   => "161",
        "alt"   => "Kitten Maker animal game",
        "title" => "Create the kitten or cub of your dreams!",
        "tags"  => array ("animals", "feline", "cats", "mega hits"),
     ),
}
```

Here's a larger part of the code, to put into context.  It pulls from the array of ~400 games, and pulls the ones with a specific tag:

```
function array_subset($arr) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($page_tag, $value["tags"])){
            if(is_array($value)) $newArray[$key] = array_copy($value);
            else if(is_object($value)) $newArray[$key] = clone $value;
            else $newArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}
function array_copy($arr) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) $newArray[$key] = array_copy($value);
        else if(is_object($value)) $newArray[$key] = clone $value;
        else $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $newArray;
}
$games_list = array();
$games_list = array_subset($GAMES_REPOSITORY);
$games_list = array_reverse($games_list);
```

Oh, an interesting hint.  Elsewhere it DOES work using $_GET:

```
if (in_array($_GET[tagged], $value[tags])){
```

Comment: show your array

Comment: @iCoders I added a piece of the array to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work!  I don't entirely understand why, but I had to feed the variable into the function directly.  For some reason it wouldn't pull the variable from the parent function.  But now it works and it even takes two dynamic variables:

```
function array_subset2($arr, $tag1, $tag2) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($tag1, $value['tags'])){
            if (in_array($tag2, $value['tags'])){
                if(is_array($value)) $newArray[$key] = array_copy2($value);
                else if(is_object($value)) $newArray[$key] = clone $value;
                else $newArray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}
function array_copy2($arr) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) $newArray[$key] = array_copy2($value);
        else if(is_object($value)) $newArray[$key] = clone $value;
        else $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $newArray;
}
$games_list = array();
$games_list = array_subset2($GAMES_REPOSITORY, $page_tag, $featured_secondary_tag);
```

Answer (score 1):

The *in_array()* function can check variables, so it is likely that your problem comes from somewhere else. Verify that you've defined your constant *tags* correctly. If it's not defined, it might not work depending on your PHP version. Some versions just assume that you wanted to write the string *tags* instead of a constant named *tags*.

Your code works. Here's a full example that I've tested that works well:

```php
<?php
const tags = "tags";
$page_tag = 'animals';
$value = array('tags' => array("fruits", "animals"));

if (in_array($page_tag, $value[tags])){
   echo "yes";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Brian I added a piece of the array to the question.  Okay, good to know that the code works.  I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate your answer...

Comment: Have you tried writing $value["tags"] instead of $value[tags] ?

Comment: Trying now. No, didn't work.  I assumed that part wasn't the problem because  in_array('animals', $value[tags]) does work...?

Comment: Well, your syntax is correct. So, it's likely that the problem comes from somewhere else. Maybe try it that way without the constants... if (in_array($page_tag, $GAMES_REPOSITORY["Kitten Maker"]["tags"]))

Comment: Thank you.  I can't quite word it like that because it's nested in a loop, in a function.  But I think that's basically what it's doing now.  I've added more of the code... maybe I've messed something up further up the function :/

Comment: I'm going back and re-trying everything.  When I tried the const bit, I got an error, which apparently means I'm using a PHP version "before 5.3".  I wonder if that's messing stuff up.  I also tried array_search instead of in_array and I got the same issue; worked for the direct string, but not for the variable :/

Comment: I know that I have PHP 5.7, so that could explain why I don't have this issue and you do. I know it's probably not the best answer to your problem, but if you still have it, you could always try to implement the `in_array()` function yourself. You only need a `for` loop and a `if`. You might also find some implementations of it on Google. :/

Comment: 10 months later, I still need to figure this out hahaha.  I tried your code Brian, and I can get it to work no problem, even still running php 5.3.  So you're right, it isn't the syntax per se.  What in the world is going on...

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of arrays, so in_array() wont work as you have written it as that test for existence in an array, not a subarray. You may as well just loop through your arrays like this:

```
foreach($GAMES_REPOSITORY as $name =>$info) {
   if(in_array($page_tag, $info['tags']))
   {  whatever  } 
}
```

If that is not fast enough you will have to cache your tags by looping ahead of time and creating an index of tags.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing though?  I can't see significant differences between your code and mine.. (i appended more of the code near the bottom of the question later)